# Mongodb: Determining shard key strategy on compound index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, sharding

> I have a collection with 170 millions+ documents and it is only going
>   to increase. The size of the collection is not that huge, currently
>   around 70 GB.
>
> The collection has two fields **indexed on: {AgentId:1, PropertyId:1}**.
>   Generally one imports a huge file(millions of documents) belonging to
>   a particular A**gentId but the PropertyId(non numeric nullable) is
>   mostly random unique value.**
>
> Currently I have **two shards with shard key based on {_id: hashed}**. But
>   I am planning to **change the shard key to  compound Index {AgentId:1,
>   PropertyId:1}** because I think it will improve query performance( most
>   of the queries are based on AgentId filter). Not sure whether one can
>   have a nullable field in the shard key. If this is the case then app
>   will make sure that the PropertyId is random no.
>
> So looking to get a picture as to
>
> 1. How the data will be distributed to shards during insertion
>      and how the range of a chunks are calculated during insertion?
>
>    2. Since the PropertyId is random value. Does the compound key fits the 
>         definition of monotonically increasing value?
>
> I am a newbie to mongodb. And wanted to know if I am on the right path?
>
> Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is **no automatic support in MongoDB for changing a shard key after sharding a collection**.

This reality underscores the importance of choosing a good shard key. If you must change a shard key after sharding a collection, the best option is to:

1. dump all data from MongoDB into an external format.
2. drop the original sharded collection.
3. configure sharding using a more ideal shard key.
4. pre-split the shard key range to ensure initial even distribution.
5. restore the dumped data into MongoDB.